How do we know if our Bioacoustics Stack Exchange is having an impact on our community/science?
Just about 2 years into this, we have had (to my knowledge), our first acknowledgement in a publication. A question asked here resulted in several helpful answers and even a paper implementing one of the suggested methods.
Many thanks to Francesca (@fterranova) for bringing their recent publication to our attention.
Terranova et al. 2024. Science of the Total Environment. Windy Events detection in big bioacoustics datasets using a pre-trained Convolutional Neural Network. 949: 174868 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048969724050174?via%3Dihub#ac0005
https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/a/1701/42


This is amazing!!! And it makes me wonder---How do we know we are making an impact, and how do we expand that impact?
